# Same answer 10 times for a mock invocation, and then another answer after that, with Mockito

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

I want my mock to return `method1()` when called 10 times and return `method2()` when called after that. The code below works with an anonymous inner class. Is there an elegant way to do this in Java 8?

```
when(mock.doSomething()).thenAnswer(
    new Answer<Account>() {
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        public Account answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            if (count < 10) {
                count++;
                return method1();
            }
            return method2();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since mutable state like a counter and Java 8’s lambda expressions do not work well together, there is no straight-forward, Java 8 specific solution with a counter. And every attempt to find a clever work-around will be worse than the following, counter-free solution

```
public static <T> OngoingStubbing<T> switchAfter(
              OngoingStubbing<T> stub, int calls, Supplier<T> first, Supplier<T> then) {
    Answer<T> a1=x -> first.get(), a2=x -> then.get();
    while(calls-->0) stub=stub.then(a1);
    return stub.then(a2);
}
```

which is just the equivalent of using

```
Mockito.when(mock.doSomething()).then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1())
       .then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1())
       .then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1()).then(x -> method1())
       .then(x -> method2());
```

Usable as

```
switchAfter(Mockito.when(mock.doSomething()), 10, () -> method1(), () -> method2());
```

---

Thinking about it again, there is a solution which is not simpler in terms of code, but preferable if the count of first calls is large:

```
public static <T> Answer<T> switchAfter(int calls, Supplier<T> first, Supplier<T> then) {
    Iterator<T> it=Stream.concat(
            IntStream.range(0, calls).mapToObj(i -> first.get()),
            Stream.generate(then))
        .iterator();
    return x -> it.next();
}
```

usable as

```
Mockito.when(mock.doSomething()).then(switchAfter(10, () -> method1(), () -> method2()));
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Answer` is a single-method interface so you may be able to simplify the anonymous inner class boilerplate. I don't think there's any built-in alternative to simplify your logic unless you were to extract it to a method you write (like `firstNTimes(invocation -> method1(), 10, invocation -> method2())`).

```
when(mock.doSomething()).thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
  if (count < 10) {
    count++;
    return method1();
  }
  return method2();
});
```

I didn't get a chance to test this; if the `Throwable` or Answer generics cause you any trouble, please comment and I'll take another look.

Comment: You dodged the required declaration of `count`. Since this doesn’t work if `count` is a local variable, it has to be declared somewhere else…

Comment: Yep, this wouldn't work because we are mutating the count declared some where as final and it would throw a compile error.

Comment: @Holger True, and though you could easily make a `final` reference to a mutable object (like AtomicInteger) to track the count, I agree that makes it look a little less pithy than one would hope for.

Comment: When creating an object to hold the mutable variable and replacing `count++` with `getAndIncrement()` (in case of using an `AtomicInteger`), you loose any advantage of the lambda expression over the original anonymous inner class approach regarding both, (source code) simplicity and (runtime) performance…